# Can't tap on images with navigationLink

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var recipes: [Recipe] = []


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
        
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns:  [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())], spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(recipes) { recipe in
                    NavigationLink(destination: RecipeDetailView()) {
                        Image(recipe.coverPhoto)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                            .cornerRadius(0)
                            .overlay(
                                Text(recipe.name)
                                    .font(.custom("Bodoni 72 Book", size: 20))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 0, x: 1, y: 1)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                                ,
                                alignment: .bottom
                            )
                            .padding(.bottom,0.5)
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Recipes")
        .onAppear {
            do {
                if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "recipes", withExtension: "json") {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    self.recipes = try decoder.decode([Recipe].self, from: data)
                } else {
                    print("JSON file not found")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am using SwiftUI and Why can't I tap on the images with this code to go the destination? Nothing happens, no errors.

I get the details from json file and it displays perfectly on screen, with images and titles. But cant seem to find why nothing happens when I tap them.

Tried with real device, simulator. I tried List. I was doing with LazyVGrid but tried without it as well.

Edit:

```
struct Recipe: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
let name: String
let instructions: String
let ingredients: [String]
let garnish: String
let coverPhoto: String
var id: UUID {
    return UUID()
}
```

}

Comment: Is the `ScrollView` within a `NavigationView`? If that is the case could you please provide further code?

Comment: @Carsten sure updated code to show the whole block

Comment: All works well for me in my tests, on MacOS 13.4, Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
It could be different on older systems. Could be due to other code you are not showing. Note `NavigationView` is deprecated you should use `NavigationStack`

Comment: I tested it with a dummy view and it is working as expected. Here is my [test view](https://gist.github.com/car5ten/202e9c4c13e6b44c07d40fbc045a4a6a)

Comment: @Carsten Ah! It was the missing id: \.self in for each. Thank you so much. you can put it as an answer I can accept the answer if you wish.

Comment: @Ataman if adding `id: \.self` is fixing the problem there might be an issue with `Recipe` itself. Can you provide the `Recipe` code?

Comment: @Carsten Added to the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is within `Recipe`: SwiftUI is re-rendering the view, but keep the state of `recipes`. On every re-render the view is getting the `id` for each `Recipe`. Since `id` is a computed property it returns a new `UUID` on each call. Therefore the List can't identify the correct recipe and the `NavigationLink` isn't working as expected.

To fix your issue you need to change `Recipe`:

```swift
struct Recipe: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    let instructions: String
    let ingredients: [String]
    let garnish: String
    let coverPhoto: String
    let id: UUID

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.instructions = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .instructions)
        self.ingredients = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .ingredients)
        self.garnish = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .garnish)
        self.coverPhoto = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .coverPhoto)
        self.id = UUID() // cruical change
    }
}
```